# Rails Form to update Attribute from a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an App with Demos and Ratings. The basic idea is that each user can rate demos, and they can update the ratings. However, I'm having a lot of errors with several things:

1. Updating the rating for the demo
2. Creating a form to update the rating

**Demo Controller**

```
def show
    @demo = Demo.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(@demo.user_id)
    @topic = Subject.find(@demo.subject_id)
    if repeat_reviewer?(current_user)
        @rating = Rating.create(reviewer: current_user, reviewed: @demo)
    else
        @rating = Rating.where(reviewer: current_user, reviewed: @demo)
    end
end

....

def repeat_reviewer?(user)
    @demo = Demo.find(params[:id])
    return false unless user == User.where(reviewed: @demo)
end

def update_average_rating
    @value = 0
    self.ratings.each do |r|
        @rating += @rating.value 
    end
    @total = self.ratings.size

    update_attributes(rating_average: @value.to_f / @total.to_f)
end
```

**Ratings Controller**

```
before_action :require_user, only: [:create, :update]
after_action :update_demo_rating

def create
    @rating = Rating.create(rating_params)
    if @rating.save 
        redirect_back_or
    end
end

def update
  @rating = Rating.where(reviewer: current_user)
  if @rating.update_attributes(rating_params)
    redirect_back_or
  end
end

private

def rating_params
    params.require(:rating).permit(:value, :reviewer_id, :reviewed_id)
end

def update_demo_rating
    @rating = Rating.find(params[:id])
    @demo = @rating.reviewed
    @demo.update_average_rating
end
```

**Demos Show View**

```
<%= form_for @rating, url: ratings_path(@rating), method: :put do |f| %>
<%= options_for_select([[5,5],[3,3],[1,1]], 1) %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

I have errors with generating the form, with updating the correct attributes, and also find the rating associated with the demo and user.

Comment: `user == User.where(reviewed: @demo)` - this is improper comparison as `.where` returns array

Comment: `update_average_rating` does not seem to belong in a controller. Did you mean it is in the model?

Comment: The update_average_rating is in the demos controller and it's being called in the ratings controller... I struggled with WHERE because I cant get a way to find the right rating